Logitech G435 Lightspeed wireless headphones linked audio levels
The problem is that when you change the volume on the headphones and through the slider on the windows, the main volume also changes, which makes them very quiet, this is because when you change the "headset earphone" volume, the main volume changes with them, somehow I managed to unlink them (but it was six-seven months ago) and leave the main volume at 99, and everything worked fine, but now this problem has appeared again, is there any option to unlink these two sliders?
I use them through the LIGHTSPEED adapter

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
